# Extract column and row name of minimum value per group

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I want to extract the name of the column and row with the minimum value, grouped by the species name. Such as if the DB is the example below, it will be the result will be V1(column name) and ow(row name) for species Ag, V1 and pre for species Au, and V1 and post for species Bri.

```
species <- rep(c("Ag", "Au", "Bri"), each=4)
period<- rep(c("ow", "pre", "fp", "post"), l=12)
V1 <- c(1,3,5,10,18,3,15,6,3,3,46,1)
V2 <- c(2,4,5,2,8,13,5,98,54,34,56,11)
df<-data.frame(species, period, V1, V2)
```

I tried first with the column name but not even that worked:

```
AIC.min<- df %>%
group_by(species) %>%
mutate(min.model = names(df[2:3])[apply(df[2:3],1,function(x) which(x==min(x)))])
```

I also tried with filter and select, as well with aggregate instead of apply following similar questions but did not succeeded. None work for me, here I get an error message "Error in names(models.AIC.all[2:8])[apply(models.AIC.all[2:8], 1, function(x) which(x ==  : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'"

Anyone could advise would be incredible awesome!

Comment: Do you realize that you are creating a `matrix`, and all numbers are converted to strings? (If not, use `data.frame` in place of `cbind`.)

Comment: Do you needd `lapply(split(df[3:4], df$species), function(x) which(x == min(as.matrix(x)), arr.ind = TRUE))`

Comment: Please add AIC.min: `object 'AIC.min' not found`.

Comment: If you need only the column names, then try with `max.col` `stack(lapply(split(df[3:4], df$species), function(x) names(x)[max.col(-x, "first")]))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `gather()` on the two columns with values, then `mutate()` to find the lowest for each species-period pairing, and `filter()` to return the columns.

```r
df %>% gather(k,v,-period,-species) %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% mutate(low=ifelse(v==min(v),1,0)) %>% 
  filter(low==1)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   species [3]
  species period k         v   low
  <fct>   <fct>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Ag      ow     V1        1     1
2 Au      pre    V1        3     1
3 Bri     post   V1        1     1
```

Comment: Yeah, this works!!! had a silly mistake when trying it first. I think I need a break...Thanks a million. Also @akrun approach worked BTW, this is just more straight forward to get the names!

Comment: That is because you are using `cbind` on your 4 variables before passing them to the `data.frame`, which cause the numeric values to be changed to strings (i.e., '13' < '3' as a string, so the Au-pre pair returns 13). Either remove `cbind`, or `mutate` the value column to numeric after gathering the variables. `df %>% gather(k,v,-period,-species) %>% mutate(v=as.numeric(v)) %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% mutate(low=ifelse(v==min(v),1,0)) %>% 
  filter(low==1)`

Comment: Yes, I realised! And fixed it =)